# Crashed when pass va_list to FMDB executeUpdate function

Tags: ios, objective-c, fmdb, variadic-functions

I have one method which accepts va_list like this:

```
+(NSUInteger) addObjectToDB:(NSString*)dbFilePath withSQL:(NSString*)sql, ... {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, sql);

    FMDatabaseQueue* dbQ = [FMDatabaseQueue databaseQueueWithPath:dbFilePath];
    __block NSUInteger result = -1;

    [dbQ inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *db) {
        [db open];

        if ([db executeUpdate:sql, args]) {
            result = (NSUInteger) [db lastInsertRowId];
        }

        [db close];
    }];

    va_end(args);

    return result;
}
```

#### EDIT1:

I want to pass va_list(args) to the 'executeUpdate:' method of FMDatabase like this:

```
NSString* sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Insert Into Table_Name Values (NULL, '%@', ?, ?)", @"string"]; 
[CXDBHelper addObjectToDB:self.dbFilePath withSQL:sql, NSData, NSData];
```

but the execution stopped in the method (FMDatabase.m) :

```
- (void)bindObject:(id)obj toColumn:(int)idx inStatement:(sqlite3_stmt*)pStmt {

    if ((!obj) || ((NSNull *)obj == [NSNull null])) {
        sqlite3_bind_null(pStmt, idx);
    }

    // FIXME - someday check the return codes on these binds.
    else if ([obj isKindOfClass:[NSData class]]) {
```

at the last line without error message.

#### EDIT 2:

Thanks to @rmaddy's tips, I check the code `executeUpdate:`, it is defined as:

```
- (BOOL)executeUpdate:(NSString*)sql, ...
```

I realize that the problem is I cannot pass a va_list to it.

#### EDIT 3:

At last, I use another method which accept va_list: `executeUpdate: withVAList:` and everything is OK now.

Comment: And the details of the crash are...?

Comment: Are you passing and argument that isn't a subclass of NSObject? I get crashes with no errors when I try to pass, for instance, an int, instead of a [NSNumber numberWithInt:myInt]

Comment: @Will  I passed NSData.

Comment: @rmaddy  I call the method like this: `NSString* sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Insert Into Table_Name Values (NULL, '%@', ?, ?)", @"string"];` `[CXDBHelper addObjectToDB:self.dbFilePath withSQL:sql, NSData, NSData];`

Comment: You need to post details about the crash. What is the complete and exact error message? Which line causes the crash?

Comment: BTW - you can't do what you are trying to do. You can't pass `args` that way unless the `executeUpdate:` method is specifically written to take a `va_list` parameter (which it isn't).

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you very much for your tips, I get the point, and everything is OK now. The question was updated.